# How to post to other domain and get result html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Browser must send POST request and receive result html page from javascript.
There is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin in server response. It is not possible to change anything is server.

If human clicks is submit button, response is returned propery.

Trying same from javascript using:

```
        $.ajax('https://example.com', {
            data: 
                {
                    postkey: 'value'
                }
            method: 'POST',
            async: false
        })
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            });
```

returns exception in chrome console:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:52216' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I also tried jsonp

```
        $.ajax('https://example.com', {
            data: 
                {
                    postkey: 'value'
                }
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false
        })
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            });
```

In this case request type is changed to GET and stange error in chrome console occurs:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Chrome developer tools shows that in both cases example.com server returned proper html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="et">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="et">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
...
```

How to fix this in client side ? I need to emulate click in form submit button and get result html page.

Jquery, Bootstrap 3 and  jquery UI are used.
In server Apache, Mono, mod_mono, ASP .NET MVC 4.6 are used.

It is possbile to create MVC controller in server which invokes such request and returns result. I'm looking for a way to do it from browser, without extra application own server call.

** Update **

From 
[How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript) jcubic answer I found sample:

> There is one more way (using html5 feature). You can use proxy iframe
>   hosted on that other domain, you send message using postMessage to
>   that iframe, then that iframe can do POST request (on same domain) and
>   postMessage back with reposnse to the parent window.

parent on sender.com

```
var win = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow;

win.postMessage(JSON.stringify({url: "URL", data: {}}),"http://reciver.com");

function get(event) {
    if (event.origin === "http://reciver.com") {
        // event.data is response from POST
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener){
    addEventListener("message", get, false)
} else {
    attachEvent("onmessage", get)
}
```

iframe on reciver.com

```
function listener(event) {
    if (event.origin === "http://sender.com") {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        $.post(data.url, data.data, function(reponse) {
            window.parent.postMessage(reponse, "*");
        });
    }
}
// don't know if we can use jQuery here
if (window.addEventListener){
    addEventListener("message", listener, false)
} else {
    attachEvent("onmessage", listener)
}
```

Also this is described in http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html

Will this work on current browsers and is this resonable ?
Is there some generic method or plugin which implements this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you own the domain you are posting to, you won't be able to post to a different domain from the one that originated the request.

Comment: If there is regular form and human clicks submit button it works. Maybe it is possible to create hidden form or use iframe for this to get results back in javascript ? I can create MVC controller in my server which makes such request but I'm looking for a way to call example.com directly from browser without making extra call to my server

Comment: Yes. For first sample exception occurs in XMLHttp send() method. It liiks like browser throws exception and does not return data. For second method console does not show code which causes the error. No sure which causes this. I updated question with possible solution. Is this reasonable, will it work ?

Comment: JSONP will only work if that site you're POSTing to supports it, which means wrapping the result into a JS function call. For that iframe solution, again it will only work if you control the site, but in this case enabling CORS seems to be less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AJAX and run a curl post on the PHP script side